# What is the right way to filter data with Prisma where I have to use a string property inside of a JSON field?

Tags: prisma

This is the Prisma schema with mySQL:

```
model Post {
  id          Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  content     Json?          @default("{}")

}
```

The content JSON field has this structure:

```
{
   photos:[
        { id:3, title:"XXX" } , { id:2, title:"XYY" }, { id:2, title:"YY" }
    ]
}
```

My goal is to match any record where one of its "photos"'s title contains an "X".  According to:

[https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/special-fields-and-types/working-with-json-fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/880xF.png)

So my query is:

```
prisma.post.findMany({
    where:{
      content:{
            path: '$.photos[*].title',
            array_contains: 'X',
       }
    }
});
```

This does not work. I tried array_starts_with, string_contains, string_starts_with but still returned 0 results. What is wrong with my query?

Comment: First of all, why do you store such information within a json field? If you are using a relational database, then use it as a relational database and create a separate table for photos with a foreign key pointing to the posts table. Each photo would be stored as row in the photos table. Searching the photos table would be a lot easier as well using the like operator.

Comment: My use case is: the data structure should be flexible enough but does not require adding more tables to do it. The  JSON field would act as a "consumer app" customized content, like in this case a photo app would have that photos field, another app like blog app would probably be using a sections field, a ecommerce cart would be using products list+totalAmount..etc...  All queries and mutations would be handled by that "consumer app"

Comment: If you have to search within the json stored within a column, then a relational database can't use indexes, so you lose any advantage and feature a relational database can orovide you with. Relational database is not suitable for tour requirements or you are misusing relational databases. Eaxh application can have its specific table instead of json.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think my JSON query works now.